# Why does my small React project respond terribly when the window is resized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a small project to learn more about react and have noticed that the view responds very poorly when the window size is changed.

I feel i must be doing something somewhere i shouldn't and that is creating this cumbersome experience.

Here's my app:

```
import ColourCard from "./components/colour-card";

const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/data/master/css/syntaxes.json";

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            error: null,
            colours: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch(url)
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then( data => {

                let colours = data['named-color']['syntax'].split(' | ');

                colours = colours.filter((colour) => {

                    return !colour.includes('gray') && !colour.includes('transparent');
                });

                this.setState({ colours });

                let clipboard = new Clipboard('.js-copy');

                clipboard.on('success', function(e) {

                    const el = e.trigger.closest('.card').parentNode.getElementsByClassName('card-flash')[0];

                    el.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML = e.text;

                    el.classList.add('active');

                    setTimeout(() => el.classList.remove('active'), 1000);
                });
            })
            .catch( e => this.setState({ error: 'Ooops, error' }) )
    }

    render() {

        const { error, colours } = this.state;

        if ( error ) {

            return <div>{error}</div>
        }

        if ( !colours.length ) {

            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return (

            <div className="grid">

                {colours.map((colour, index) => {

                    return <ColourCard colour={colour} key={index}></ColourCard>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

and heres my card component:

```
class ColourCard extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const colour = tinycolor(this.props.colour);

        const style = {

            backgroundColor: colour.toHexString()
        };

        return (

            <div className="grid__item  size-6@m  size-4@l">

                <div className="card">

                    <div className="card__colour" style={style}></div>

                    <div className="card__meta">

                        <div className="card__meta-item  js-copy" data-clipboard-text={this.props.colour}>{this.props.colour}</div>

                        <div className="card__meta-item  js-copy" data-clipboard-text={colour.toHexString()}>{colour.toHexString()}</div>

                        <div className="card__meta-item  js-copy" data-clipboard-text={colour.toRgbString()}>{colour.toRgbString()}</div>

                        <div className="card__meta-item  js-copy" data-clipboard-text={colour.toHslString()}>{colour.toHslString()}</div>

                        <div className="card__meta-item  js-copy" data-clipboard-text={colour.toHsvString()}>{colour.toHsvString()}</div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div className="card-flash" style={style}>

                    <span className="card-flash__text">
                        <strong className="card-flash__strong"></strong>
                        <br />
                        Copied!
                    </span>

                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ColourCard;
```

https://codepen.io/matt3224/project/editor/ZvLGGA#

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This whole block of code here:

```
            let clipboard = new Clipboard('.js-copy');

            clipboard.on('success', function(e) {

                const el = e.trigger.closest('.card').parentNode.getElementsByClassName('card-flash')[0];

                el.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML = e.text;

                el.classList.add('active');

                setTimeout(() => el.classList.remove('active'), 1000);
            });
```

You are **never** supposed to manually manipulate the DOM with react. That is really the one golden rule when using this library. This is the same reason why libraries like `d3` have trouble with react, because it wants to get its hand into the DOM. React manages a virtual DOM, and any interference with that is not good. It can lead to performance issues and generally speaking, will break your app more times than not.

Comment: I see, how can i do what i want to do via react? rather than what i have above

Comment: You need to use your state and your jsx. so for example, this line `el.classList.add('active')` -- what you should be doing is modifying your state and then having your jsx listen in on that on its `className` - something like `className={this.state.active ? 'active' : ''}`

Comment: I have just to test, commented the offending code but it's still quite laggy. Am I doing anything else wrong? https://71b39fcefff9415289c6746d496a64b3.codepen.website

Comment: I just tried your codepen, was not laggy for me. I'm not really sure what else could be wrong, it looks fine.